# Getting tables in lua

Tags: lua

Is it possible to get all tables inside of another script using lua? this is for a roblox hack btw
anyways I have a method but it is extremly laggy because it gets every table in the hole game

Answer (score 1):

If that script returns references to those tables or if that script creates global table values you can do that.
Otherwise you can't as those tables are local to that script's scope.